# Generate symfony 2.4 password from Python/Django

Tags: python, django, symfony, passwords

I'm working on a project where i have to insert user into a database from a Python/django application.
Those users authenticate themselves in a symfony 2.4 application so i have to generate a password that will be decrypted properly.

The symfony project use the sha256 algorythm (as i can see in the security.yml file)

Do you have some informations about the way symfony 2 encode the password with this algorythm ? (I know i have to build a salt and a hash)

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking us how to build sha-256 hashes from strings? If so, here ya go friend. Don't crack any accounts with this, that would be illegal, mkay? https://www.pythoncentral.io/hashing-strings-with-python/

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) But my question is how to encrypt a password for symfony 2 with python. The encoder used in the symfony is sha256 but it's not just a simple hash

Comment: Their documentation gives an example of using their code to generate pw hashes here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/password_encoding.html/ I assume you could either look directly in the sources of the code to see what encoding and salt they use and using the link I provided above, try to generate one yourself then compare it to the one generated using their code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just call symfony command externally to generate password, parse it and store it to your db (of course, if you have an access to the symfony side)?

Something like this:

```
import os
os.system('cd SYMFONY_DIR && php app/console security:encode-password "MY_PASSWORD"  "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User" > tmp')
encOutput = open('tmp', 'r').read()
// Parse it here
```

Here, `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User` is the registered class to encoder, you can find the proper one in the `security.yml`

Just an idea..

Comment: That's an idea yes, but sadly my code won't have access to the symfony library from where it will be executed.